# Duplicate WEB-INF folder created with maven build with package goal from Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web-applications

I have created a maven application with JSF, Spring and JSF facets. The goals clean (deleting the target directory) and compile are working fine. But when I am running Maven with package option, I see that in the generated xxx-SNAPSHOT.war file the webapp and WEB-INF directory are copied recursively.

The Maven version is 3.1.0.

Please see the below pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.organization.elr</groupId>
    <artifactId>employeerepository</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Employee Location Repository</name>
    <properties>
        <version.spring>3.1.2.RELEASE</version.spring>
        <version.aopalliance>1.0</version.aopalliance>
        <version.standard.taglibs>1.1.2</version.standard.taglibs>
        <version.commons.logging>1.1.1</version.commons.logging>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/WEB-INF/classes/test</testOutputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Any ideas how I can avoid this?

Thanks in advance,
Mouli.

Comment: can you post the directory structure after package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense

```
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/WEB-INF/classes/test</testOutputDirectory>
```

Remove those lines. You're building application to source dir.

This have no sense as well

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Why do you have .java files in resources in the first place?

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the responses. I have got those junk lines copy pasted from  sample projects. It has been removed now and everything is as per the plan.

Best Regards,
Chandra.